# Mongoimport and mongorestore does not work on Atlas free tier

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas, mongoimport, mongorestore

I want to migrate from Azure Cosmos Db to Mongo Db Atlas (on Azure), so I am testing in a subscription with a free tier.
I exported a collection from Cosmos with mongoexport and tried to import on Mongo with mongoexport but it runs without an end logging 0% progress, even with a partial extraction of data (16,5 mb). I tried with mongodump and mongorestore but it seems to do nothing (no error or log is shown).
I did not find any limitation in https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/free-shared-limitations/ or unsupport commands https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/unsupported-commands/ for the free tier.

Log using -vvvv options

Mongorestore

```
2020-12-01T16:14:20.910+0100 checking options 
2020-12-01T16:14:21.070+0100 dumping with object check disabled 
2020-12-01T16:14:21.072+0100 will listen for SIGTERM, SIGINT, and SIGKILL
```

Never stop

Mongoimport

```
2020-12-02T10:14:07.284+0100    will listen for SIGTERM, SIGINT, and SIGKILL
2020-12-02T10:14:07.445+0100    using 4 decoding workers
2020-12-02T10:14:07.446+0100    using 1 insert workers
2020-12-02T10:14:07.449+0100    filesize: 17263803 bytes
2020-12-02T10:14:07.449+0100    using fields:
2020-12-02T10:14:10.451+0100    [........................] MigrationTest.HotWater       0B/16.5MB (0.0%)
2020-12-02T10:14:13.451+0100    [........................] MigrationTest.HotWater       0B/16.5MB (0.0%)
2020-12-02T10:14:50.678+0100    [........................] MigrationTest.HotWater       0B/16.5MB (0.0%)
2020-12-02T10:14:52.452+0100    [........................] MigrationTest.HotWater       0B/16.5MB (0.0%)
```

Continuous logging of last row, never stop in the same way

Any hints?

Thanks

Comment: Configure your IP whitelist.

Comment: All IPs are allowed

Comment: There are timeouts on all operations. Use verbose option to see what is happening. https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/mongorestore/#cmdoption-mongorestore-verbose

Comment: I tried but -v option does not show anything

Comment: Add the complete log with -vvvv option.

Comment: Same as -v: 2020-12-01T16:14:20.910+0100    checking options
2020-12-01T16:14:21.070+0100            dumping with object check disabled
2020-12-01T16:14:21.072+0100    will listen for SIGTERM, SIGINT, and SIGKILL
2020-12-01T17:19:31.262+0100    signal 'interrupt' received; attempting to shut down
2020-12-01T17:19:31.474+0100    signal 'interrupt' received; forcefully terminating

Comment: Add that to the question and do not interrupt the program.

Comment: Does mongo shell connection work?

Comment: Yes, it correctly connects

Answer (score 0):

I have come across this problem, and fixed it by uninstalling my local version of mongo (which involved manually deleting the various mongo db tools, including mongorestore), and then reinstalling the mongo db tools. I then ran mongoimport against each collection instead of mongorestore.

The [documentation also says](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/mongorestore/#restore-to-matching-server-version) that the mongodb major version from which you exported should match the version to into which you are importing/restoring the data.